# Google Calendar API V3 - Event.Recurrence always null

Tags: c#, .net, events, calendar, google-calendar-api

I try to create a Calendar Synchronisation between my Application and the Google Calendar.

But now I have a Problem I just can't solve..

I'm getting all Events from the Calendar like this:

```
EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List("primary");
request.TimeMin = new DateTime(1990,1,1);
request.ShowDeleted = false;
request.SingleEvents = true;
request.MaxResults = 1000;
request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

Events events = request.Execute();
foreach(Event ev in events.Items)
{
    String s = ev.Recurrence;//Recurrence is always null
}
```

But `ev.Recurrence` is never filled, also when `ev.RecurringEventId` is filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recurrence property of the Event object is not populated for single events or instances of the recurring event. This is what google is saying about that field:

> This field contains list of RRULE, EXRULE, RDATE and EXDATE lines for a recurring event,
>   as specified in RFC5545. Note that DTSTART and DTEND lines are not
>   allowed in this field; event start and end times are specified in the
>   start and end fields. This field is omitted for single events or
>   instances of recurring events.

RecurringEventId property of the Event object is provided, well, for instances of the recurring event. It's not gonna be populated for the non-recurring events.

Comment: Then how can i get the reference to the recurrence of a single instance?

Comment: @Kenshinaro Short answer:you cannot. Recurrence does not make sense for single events anyway. That's why Google decided not to populate it in described cases.

Comment: That makes no Sense to me.. when i have a Single Event instance of a recurring Event there must be a was to get the recurrence

Comment: @Kenshinaro I thought you were talking about non-recurring events.:) For recurring events RecurringEventId field  would be populated with an id of the parent event this instance belongs to. On top of that you have to use Instances call instead of List to work with instances of the recurring event.